# How to add background image for options in a select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

Can anyone give me a cross-browser supported solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom jquery plugin like in this reference:

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

Answer (score 2):

HTML:- You can use inline style like below,

```
<select>
    <option style="background-image:url(1stimage.gif);">1</option>
    <option style="background-image:url(2ndimage.gif);">2</option>
    <option style="background-image:url(3rdimage.gif);">3</option>
</select>
```

The above code would work in Firefox and Webkit browsers. For rest of the browsers you can use JQuery UI, please find the link below

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Selectable

EDIT: You can also try this http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx

Comment: The link was exactly what I needed to make my own dropdown, having already tried to use the msdropdown in the accepted answer.  (msdropdown is brilliant, but I found it hard to get it to match my other jQuery widgets.)

Comment: I believe background images do not work on option elements.

Comment: This works only on Firefox

Comment: its not working in chrome