# photos in select-option are not shawn in chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a little problem with the select option!
the problem is that if i put photos in the list they are displayed in Fire-Fox but in chrome they are not !!

this is my code :

```js
function change() {
 
select = document.getElementById("select");
select_s = select.style;
 
switch(select.selectedIndex) {
 
case 0 :
select_s.background = "url('http://apistudyabroad.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/API-custom/images/study_abroad_uae_flag.png') no-repeat";
break;
 
case 1 :
select_s.background = "url('http://apistudyabroad.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/API-custom/images/study_abroad_uae_flag.png') no-repeat";
break;
}
}
```

```html
<body>
 
<select id="select" onchange="change();">
<option style="background:url('http://apistudyabroad.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/API-custom/images/study_abroad_uae_flag.png') no-repeat; width:100px; height:100px;"></option>
<option style="background:url('http://apistudyabroad.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/API-custom/images/study_abroad_uae_flag.png') no-repeat; width:100px; height:100px;" </option>
</select>
 
 
</body>
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 4):

I guess there is not way of doing that. Only Firefox support this feature, in order to get this work in other browser you should use some JQuery plugin.

Check [ddSlick](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) instead, could be useful in your case

Comment: thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="select" onchange="change();">
<option style="background:url('http://apistudyabroad.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/API-custom/images/study_abroad_uae_flag.png') no-repeat; width:100px; height:100px;"></option>
<option style="background:url('http://apistudyabroad.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/API-custom/images/study_abroad_uae_flag.png') no-repeat; width:100px; height:100px;"></option>
</select>
```

The above code would work in Firefox and Webkit browsers. For rest of the browsers you can use JQuery UI, please find the link below

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Selectable

You can also try this http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx

Source:
[How to add background image for options in a select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207223/how-to-add-background-image-for-options-in-a-select-box)