# How to put pixel inside selectbox option in PHP

Tags: php, html, html-select

I'm trying to add single pixel into selectbox before text of each option.

I'm green-yellow colorblind, I made this only so you know what I would like to achieve(dont expect that colors will be accurate):
[image]

My html takes options out of foreach loop

```
<select name="selectbox" class="form-control">
     <option value=""></option>
   <? foreach ($this->color as $item): ?>
     <option value="<?= $item ?>" <? if ($item == $this->model['item']): ?> selected<? endif ?> > <?= $item ?> </option>
   <? endforeach ?>
</select>
```

which loops by controller function and returns view:

```
return $this->view //->assign('groups', $this->model->getGroups())
            ->assign('color', ['Text of Orange', 'Text of Red ', 'Text of Blue', 'Text of Yellow'])
            ->assign('something', $something)
```

**To achieve that**

I tried `imagesetpixel` and `imagepng` functions but it returns me boolean, and I dont know how could I possibly progress...

```
$gd = imagecreatetruecolor(1, 1);
$red = imagecolorallocate($gd, 255, 0, 0); 
$canvas = imagesetpixel($gd, 1, 1, $red);

return $this->view
            ->assign('color', [imagepng($canvas) + 'Text of Orange', 'Text of Red ', 'Text of Blue', 'Text of Yellow'])
```

I made only 1 color, but I hope you got the idea of what I need.

Comment: HTML `select` only supports text, not graphics or anything. Maybe look into plugins such as select2 or similar which can help you achieve this kind of functionality.

Comment: Some browsers allow background images for options, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207223/how-to-add-background-image-for-options-in-a-select-box If you need more than that, you will probably need a custom solution though.

Comment: Use https://select2.org/ !